# memory error while writing a large dataframe to S3 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a dataframe with the following shape using amazon sagemaker.

```
10612611 rows × 4 columns
```

All are numeric values.
 When I am trying to write this dataframe into my S3 bucket as follows, I get memory error.

```
bytes_to_write = df.to_csv(None).encode()
with s3.open('aws-athena-query-results-xxxxxxx/query_result/xx.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes_to_write)
```

> MemoryError:

I am using **ml.t2.medium** for sagemaker instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the instance type from **ml.t2.medium** to **ml.t2.2xlarge** and it worked perfectly.

The original issue was with the RAM of the instance type and not with S3.